# Using Google ML Engine with BigQuery?

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently designing a data warehouse in BigQuery. I'm planning to store user data like past purchases or abandoned carts.

This seems to be perfect to manually analyze trends and to get insights. But what if I want to leverage Machine Learning, e.g. to suggest products to a group of users?
I have looked into Google ML Engine and TensorFlow, and it seems like the TensorFlow model would need to query BigQuery first. In some scenarios, this could mean that TensorFlow would need to query all or most of the data that is stored in BigQuery.

This feels a bit off, so I'm wondering if this is really how things are supposed to happen. Otherwise, I assume that my ML model would have to work with stale data?

Comment: At our company we also have a BQ DW and we use it to build models as well. What we do for the most part though is to have some GAE daily cron that prepares data for each algorithm we build in some other BQ table so when the model runs all data is already setup. I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@willian.fuks/how-we-implemented-a-fully-serverless-recommender-system-using-gcp-9c9fbbdc46cc) about how we implemented our recommender system in GCP, it uses Dataproc but still you can see how we prepare data on a daily basis. It might help you on how you should do in your use case as well.

Comment: @WillianFuks - what's the best way to reach out to you outside of Stack Overflow? Want to ask you something.

Comment: @GrahamPolley Hi Graham :), if you want my email is willian.fuks in gmail or skype is also this name.

Comment: Cool. Pinged you on Skype @WillianFuks

Comment: @WillianFuks, great blog post and very relevant. Would this task be easier if you saved the data directly into Cloud Spanner or Datastore instead of BigQuery? I'm wondering if BigQuery is not the optimal storage engine if I intend to use the data for ML heavily

Comment: I don't think that these both products would be better than BQ. DS is an OLAP NoSQL DB (it's better suited for handling requests such as "is this product in stock?") and Spanner would probably be more expensive and harder to manage than BQ (I never used it though). Still, one possible strategy is daily preparing your data in whatever storage you prefer and use it from there (In the post we export our data from BQ to GCS so it's easier and cheaper for Dataproc to read it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would agree with you, using BigQuery as a data warehouse for your ML is expensive. It would be cheaper and much more efficient to use Google Cloud Storage to store all the data you wish to process. Once everything is processed and generated, you may ***then*** wish to push that data to BigQuery  push that data to another source like Spanner or even Cloud Storage.

That being said Google has now created a beta product [BigQuery ML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-analyst-start). This now allows users to create and execute machine learning models in BigQuery via the use of SQL queries. I believe it uses python and tensorflow under the hood, but I believe it would be the best solution given that you have a light weight ML load.

Since it is still in beta as of now, I don't know well it's performance compares to Google ML engine and tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of model you want to train and how you want to server the model you can do one the following options:

- You can export your data to Google Cloud Storage as CSV and then read the files in Cloud ML Engine. This will let you use the power of Tensorflow and you can then use Cloud ML Engine's serving system to send traffic to your model. 
  On the downside, this means that you have to export all of your BigQuery data to GCS and every time you decide to make any change to the data you need to go back to BigQuery and export again. Also if the data you want to prediction on is in BigQuery you have to export that as well and send it to Cloud ML Engine using a separate system.
- If you want to explore and interactively train Logistic or Linear regression models on your data, you can use [BigQuery Machine learning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-analyst-start). This will allow you to slice and dice your data in BigQuery and experiment with different parts of your data and various preprocessing options. You can also use all the power of SQL. BigQuery ML also allows you to use the model after training within BigQuery (you can use SQL to feed data in to the model).
  For many cases using full power of Tensorflow (i.e. using DNNs) is not necessary. This is especially true for structured data. On the other hand, most of your time will be spent on preprocessing and cleaning the data which would be much easier in SQL in BigQuery.

So you have two options here. Choose based on your needs.

P.S.: You can also try using [BigQuery Reader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cloud/BigQueryReader) in Tensorflow. I don't recommend it as it is very slow. But if your data is not huge it may work for you.